# Divergence in meaning of "just about" between UK and North American English

Tags: british-english, north-american-english

Does anyone know anything about how the meaning of "just about" came to have opposite meanings in the UK and North America.

For example, in the UK, ***The team just about won.*** means that the team won, but it was close (ie ***The team barely won.***). However, in North America, it means that the team almost won.

Comment: Does it really mean what you say in NA English?

Comment: It really does.

Comment: I was going to ask the converse.  Does it *really* mean that in British English?? To an American "just about" does indeed mean they came close, but failed.  If they had just about lost, then they would have won but by a slim and potentially narrowing margin.

Comment: In BrE how would this sentence be interpreted? [*Following the Second World War, the United States and Great Britain found themselves in completely opposite positions on just about every important item*](http://www.davidalanjohnson.com/the_friendliest_of_enemies__the_love___hate_relationship_between_britain_and_the_51532.htm)  Would this indicate that there were some issues on which we agreed or that we disagreed on everything?

Comment: @Jim: The former: I'd interpret it as meaning they disagreed on most things but not all.

Comment: @Hugo, Thanks. So if BrE interprets '*just about*' here to mean '*nearly*' or '*almost*' why, in "*The team just about won*", is it not interpreted as "*The team almost won*"?

Comment: @Hugo Are you saying that *just about* is used to mean *just barely* rather than *didn’t quite*?

Comment: @tchrist, that’s exactly what he’s saying. But only (if Angelo’s answer represents the actual state of affairs) in non-northern parts of England and Wales. So not really a BrE vs. AmE divide, but a SouthernpartofBritainE vs. EverythingelseE divide.

Comment: Maybe it's because I'm an Australian and hear both AmE and BrE variants of a lot of things, but I tend to use "just about" as a synonym of "more or less," so it could have both meanings.

Comment: Sorry, I don't think there is a NA/BrE difference.

Answer (score 8):

I am Scottish and we always use "just about" to mean "nearly, but not quite".
E.g. "I just about passed my exam" means "I got close to the pass mark, but didn't quite make it."

A straw poll of some of my friends indicates that Australians, New Zealanders, the Irish (both Northern Ireland and the Republic of Ireland) and those from North America (Canada and that USA) also share the same meaning as we Scots. Amongst my English and Welsh friends, I have found that only those from the north of England (Northumberland and Cumbria) share our meaning.

An interesting fact  I've noticed that is that everyone says "just about to", to mean "nearly, but not quite", e.g. "I was just about to leave when the telephone rang", meaning "I had not left, but was about to, when the telephone rang".

Answer (score 2):

When I was young, a long time ago (!), I was only aware of *just about* to mean *very nearly*, as in *Just about everyone was there* (a few people were missing) and *I just about died when I heard the news*. (I didn't actually die!)
About 20 years ago, I noticed that some sports journalists were using *just about* to mean *only just* as in *The goalkeeper just about kept the ball out*. (Meaning he saved the ball!).  Interestingly, I recently noticed a football commentator use *just about* with one meaning in one sentence and then two minutes later used it with the other and completely different meaning. I have now noticed it being used by people other than sports commentators. This wouldn't be the first time that words have come to take on another often contradictory meaning. Like all evolutionary change, what starts off as a mistake, sometimes gets accepted and repeated, but it annoys me so much, I'll resist its lure.

Answer (score 2):

British football announcers often use “just about” to mean that the objective was accomplished but by the smallest of margins whereas in the US, that phrase would imply that the objective was not accomplished narrowly. So if a Brit said, the defender just about arrived in time to block the shot, he did block it but barely.  In the US that would mean that he nearly got back in time but didn’t block it. I see from the comment above that I’m not the first to notice this.  Maybe it’s a British sport announcer thing.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

On the [Separated by a Common Language](https://separatedbyacommonlanguage.blogspot.com/2012/01/continuing-on-backlog-of-emailed.html?m=1) blog (Observations on British and American English by an American linguist in the UK) we can read the following explanation:

> The translation problem in *just about* isn't just about *just*. Let's think about *about*. The (UK) [Collins English Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/about) gives us this sense-definition, which is not to be found in the American Heritage Dictionary or Merriam-Webster:
>
> > **about**
> > 13. used in informal phrases to indicate understatement : *I've had just about enough of your insults it's about time you stopped*
>
> Aha, the famous British understatement. Rather than saying I've had enough, you put an about in to soften the blow. And then a just to soften it more.

For more details, see the site I mentioned, which seems quite well done.

Comment: We Americans use *about* that way, too, though. "I've had just about enough of your attitude." So how does this answer the OP's question and address the example the OP gives?

Comment: @JLG - Have you read the article on the site I have mentioned?

Comment: @Carlo_R. Thanks for the link. It confirms the divergence that I noted. I'm not convinced by the author that the issue is with _about_ indicating an understatement since the regional usage appears consistent. The real difference only appears in the phrase _just about_.

Comment: Yes. And the blogger goes on to make the same point I did, but she didn't ever say why there are these divergent meanings.

Comment: @Carlo_R. Interesting blogspot, I'll try to read more another day. Still, it does not help much towards understanding the reasons for different meanings. +1 anyway.

Comment: @Carlo_R I'm not convinced this answers the question.  It's not clear to me yet in any case.

Comment: Yes, but it's surely a nice contribution to which others can no doubt add.

Comment: @Paola - Thank you so much, Paola. I appreciate your support a lot!